# Why does my program crash when using SDL_RenderFillRect()?

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a program that draws to the screen, while sorting an array, like in this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg .
This is my problem: I overloaded the comparison and assign operator, and in the assign operator I want to call a `draw()` function, which will draw to the screen. But when I do this, my code fails, to be exact the line `SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r)` which causes it to crash. (it starts running then crashes, cant even end in task manager).

My code:

```
    using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = nullptr;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Rendezo algoritmus", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, 0, 0);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 100, 100, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_Rect r;
r.y = 0;
r.x = 0;
r.w = 50;
r.h = 50;


SortHelper<int> mySortInts[] = { SortHelper<int>{2}, SortHelper<int>{5}, SortHelper<int>{1}, SortHelper<int>{4}, SortHelper<int>{3} };
std::vector<SortHelper<int>> myvector(mySortInts, mySortInts + 5);

SDL_Rect *rectArr = new SDL_Rect[myvector.size()];
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
int i = 0;
int rectXCoord = 0;
int rectWidth = (SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w) / myvector.size();
for (SortHelper<int> s : myvector) {
    s.setRenderer(renderer);
    rectArr[i].w = rectWidth;
    rectArr[i].h = s.getHeight();
    rectArr[i].x = rectXCoord;
    rectArr[i].y = (SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->h) - (rectArr[i].h);
    rectXCoord += (SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w) / myvector.size();
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectArr[i]);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
SDL_Delay(500);

SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

delete[] rectArr;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

And my sorthelper.h:

```
#pragma once
class SDL_Renderer;
template<typename T>
class SortHelper {
T data;
int height;
int width;
int x;
int y;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
public:
SortHelper(SortHelper &a) { data = a.data; }
SortHelper(T a) { data = a; }
bool operator<(SortHelper a) { 
return data < a.data;
}
void operator=(SortHelper const a) { 
    data = a.data;
    height = a.height;
    draw();
    SDL_Delay(10);
}
T getValue() { return data; }
int getHeight() {

    return rand() % 500;
}
void setRenderer(SDL_Renderer *r) {
    renderer = r;
}
void draw() {       
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = x;
    r.y = y;
    r.w = width;
    r.h = height;
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}};
```

Now I might have an idea what causes the problem, but can not come up nor find any solution for it. I think what ruins the code is the `SDL_Renderer` class declaration at the start of `sorthelper.h`. But if I remove that declaration, my code won't compile giving syntax error where i declare `SDL_Renderer *renderer;`. So if I am right, my question is, how can I declare an SDL_Renderer member variable inside a class? If I am not, then what is the problem?

Comment: A quick question:  Why didn't you use vector here `SDL_Rect *rectArr = new SDL_Rect[myvector.size()];`?  Why not just: `std::vector<SDL_Rect> rectArr(myvector.size());`

Comment: I didn't think of it, but i like practicing pointers a bit, also didn't need the functionality of vector. Can change up for sure, but i dont think thats the main problem.

Comment: Also, why your `SortHelper` copy semantics differ between the user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator?  The copy constructor and assignment operator should just be doing those operations, unless you want a program full of bugs and weird behavior. As a matter of fact, the copy constructor is horribly wrong.  You are supposed to copy all of the members, not just some of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "those operations". I see what you want to say, copy constructor and assigment operatorr should be defined in a way that it's a copy constructor and an assigment operator. But i don't know how else could i draw the sorting process.

Comment: The main problem is that your copy constructor fails to copy all of the members.  What you will wind up with will be an object that is a partial copy, with the rest of the members having garbage data.  This mistake leads to very hard-to-find bugs in a program.  As to the assignment operator, it should be doing the same thing as the copy constructor, with the exception being that you're copying from an existing object to an existing object.  Instead, your assignment operator does a lot of "business logic", thus introducing side-effects that you have no control over.

Comment: To continue, when and where an assignment or copy is done is not under your control.  That code could be executed "behind your back".  That's why IMO they should be restricted in doing very little *except* making sure a copy is made.

Comment: Yea i can see that. Could you recommend an alternative way then, how could i draw while sorting? I can't come up with any other way than overloading the assigment operator since that's what the sorting algorythms use. Also this class is made to be used in sorting algorythms so didn't think it's that much of a problem.

Comment: *that's what the sorting algorythms use* -- Well, that's my point.  You don't know how many times that operator will be used.  It may be called once, twice, 10, or 100 times, maybe even a different number of times depending on compiler, compiler settings, optimizations, etc.  The assignment op really isn't intended to be used for business logic like that.   If you want to draw, create another thread to do the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop, `for (SortHelper<int> s : myvector)`, you're making a copy of the `myvector` elements, and working with that copy in the loop.  So the renderer within the `myvector` elements is not getting set and you're passing a null pointer into `SDL_RenderFillRect` in `draw`.

You should declare your loop as

```
for (SortHelper<int> &s : myvector)
```

Also you're not incrementing `i` in that loop, so you're always using `rectArr[0]` but that doesn't appear to matter since you only use that vector within the loop.